# Why concurrent.future executor is not using all my cores?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Here is my snippet:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def Fun(i):
    do something

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = 8) as e:
    e.map(Fun, range(10000000), chunksize = int(10000000/256))
```

I have 8 cores, however, this only uses 4 of my cores.

When I use multiprocessing module, all of my 8 cores can be used. For example:

```
with Pool(8) as p:
    p.map_async(Fun, range(10000000))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I don't understand why. In addition, if the chunk size in the `e.map()` is too large or too small, the usage of my CPU would go down, which seems not to be a problem when using multiprocessing

Comment: python 2 users: replace `range` by `xrange` to avoid consuming too much memory.

Comment: have you printed something in your `Fun` function to see how many parallel executions you really get?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the reply. How do I do this? just `print('something')`?

Comment: since they are processes you could try `print("hello from {}".format(os.getpid()))` (fully untested of course, but no risk of harming your machine!). Of course it's not an atomic print, would need some semaphore to avoid print mixups in the console: `l = multiprocessing.Lock(); l.acquire()/l.release()` should do it.